# 3D velodyne pointcloud to occuppancy grid

Tags: ros, occupancy-grid, velodyne, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I intend to use this package http://wiki.ros.org/amcl or one similir to initially localize my self in a prebuilt map. I wnat to convert my 3D map to an occupancy grid, I know how to convert it to a 2D pointcloud or a laser scan, using http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan or http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_height_map However I dont know how to convert that to an occupancy grid.
Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247759/3d-velodyne-pointcloud-to-occuppancy-grid/) by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2016-11-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To pipe laserscan or pointcloud data into an 'occupancy grid' style data structure, you can use the costmap_2d library.

http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d

You can run a standalone costmap as a node (costmap_2d_node), and configure the costmap's layers (particularly obstacle layers) to take in sensor data.

Users typically use costmap_2d as part of the navigation stack, which integrates the costmaps together with planners to give an end-to-end-ish solution for 2d navigation.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1